# Prediction from predicted/residual values compare to standard error of the estimate

Tags: regression, interpretation, prediction

I would like to indicate how good prediction is, by looking at the actual, predicted, and residual values, compare to the standard error of the estimate.

I understand that the smaller standard error of the estimate is more accurate, and is a better prediction. But when “Residual score of 27.82” is very close to “the standard error of the estimate of 34.45”, is it the good prediction, too? Actual Value is 10. I'm confused.

Actual Score: 10, 
Residual score: 27.82,
Predicted Value:  -17.82, 
Standard error of the estimate: 34.45.

THANK YOU for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated, a smaller standard error is more desirable since this minimises the standard deviation between the observed value and the actual value, which is represented by our residuals. Note that the residual score can be different depending on the observation you are looking at, so I will assume that you are referring to 27.82 as the residual at its extremity, i.e. the one furthest away from the mean.

However, the fact that these two values are numerically close, does not tell you if this result will necessarily hold as one manipulates sample size.

Recall how we calculate the standard error:
**<sup>standard deviation of the mean</sup>⁄<sub>number of observations</sub>**

As an example, let us suppose that we have an array: [10, 20.30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

Doing our calculations, we get the following results:

- Standard Deviation: 33.1662479
- Mean: 55
- Standard Error: 10
- Value of most extreme residual: 45 +/-

Now, let us suppose that our array goes up to 1000 (in a sequence of 10 as before):

- Standard Deviation: 293.0017
- Mean: 505
- Standard Error: 29.15
- Value of most extreme residual: 495 +/-

You can see that while our residual value went up in the second example, the standard error did not follow suit, because this variable adjusts for the number of observations in the sample.

Therefore, to answer your question, whether it is a "good" thing that the scores for the residual and standard error lie close together depends on the nature of your data.

You will notice that for the figures you have given, the standard error is **larger** than your residual score, and this would suggest that there is a high degree of standard deviation among your residuals. Therefore, one could not infer that the model has a high degree of predictive power simply because these two statistics lie in proximity with each other.

Comment: Mr. Grogan, Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome to Cross Validated, and if this answer proved adequate for your question, then kindly mark as solved.

Comment: Mr. Grogan, Thank you very much for your explanation!! I am actually looking at the data for various countries. So,  I would conclude that the model cannot be reliable for the country (that I am looking at), because of larger standard error of estimate than its residuals score. Thank you again